# SMail configure listening port/address?

Tags: email, debian, configuration, smtp, email-server

I try to configure my smail-system.

I want it to listen only on localhost/127.0.0.1

But when I check my system via

```
nmap myredirectingdomainname.com
```

it shows me the open port 25.

Can you help me?

Comment: smail?  Do you mean the antiquated MTA currently maintained by Greg Woods?  I'd advise that you consider using a different MTA unless you have an absolute need to use smail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use netstat to find out what's listening and fix that:

```
netstat -tpl | grep smtp
```